# Does intents updates launch training?

Tags: dialogflow-es

We synchronize the intents of our DialogFlow chatbot from our software using API.

Does an intent update automatically start chatbot training on Dialogflow?

if not, is there a way to start it using Dialogflow'api ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Training will start automatically after agent alterations.  You can instigate training manually via Dialogflow's v2 API which is documented here: https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent/train

Comment: Thanks for your help. Two last remarks : Does automatic training works even with API v1 ? Why is it needed to train the agent with your link if it is trained automatically after each updates ?

Comment: v1 API will also automatically start training when necessary.  I'm not sure why there is a training API since its not needed.

Comment: Thank you again !